# login_required decorator not redirecting to correct endpoint

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Using Flask-security extension, I was trying to protect some views, for example:

```
from flask_security import login_required

@auth.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    #...

#...

@auth.route('/change-password', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def change_password():
    #...
```

With the following `config.py` for Flask-Security:

SECURITY_URL_PREFIX           = '/auth' 
SECURITY_LOGOUT_URL          = '/signout' 
SECURITY_UNAUTHORIZED_VIEW    = '/signin'

And yet, when I try to access a protected view, I get the following `werkzeug.routing.BuildError` message:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'auth.login'.
Did you mean 'auth.signin' instead?
```

What could be the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-security uses Flask-login's `login_required` decorator and as per [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_required):

> `flask_login.login_required(func)`
>
> If you decorate a view with this, it will ensure that the current 
>    user is logged in and authenticated before calling the actual view.
>   (If they are not, it calls the **`LoginManager.unauthorized callback`**.)

While one can use `LoginManager.unauthorized callback` to setup a response:

> `unauthorized_handler(callback)`
>
> This will set the callback for the unauthorized method, which among
>   other things is used by `login_required`. It takes no arguments,
>   and should return a response to be sent to the user instead of their
>   normal view.

So, I ended up defining the callback myself:

```
 @app.login_manager.unauthorized_handler
 def unauth_handler():
      if request.is_xhr:
          return jsonify(success=False,
                         data={'login_required': True},
                         message='Authorize please to access this page.'), 401
      else:
          return redirect(url_for('auth.signin'))
```

Comment: Iron Fist where should i write this function???And should i need to write @app.login_manager.unauthorized_handler to every view or not??

Comment: @HassanShahbaz, write it in your `__init__.py` file (which is your app's init. file) if you are using factory method for creating your app. You just need to write it once and that's it.